# Label's e/ou TextFields não aparecem em subreport no JasperReports

Tags: javascript, java, jasper-reports, java-8

Tenho um relatório com sub-relatório no jasperreports, o problema e que quando executo o relatório ele não está exibindo o conteúdo das labels ou textfields que coloquei no sub-relatório, alguém já teve este problema?

Comment: Ainda desconheço o acontecimento, porém consegui averiguei que com a  versão mais atual do JasperStudio(v6.1.0 download neste [link](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jasperstudio/JaspersoftStudio-6.1.0/TIBCOJaspersoftStudio-6.1.0.final-windows-installer-x86_64.exe) ) o mesmo irá funcionar perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o tamanho da fonte do conteúdo não ultrapassa o limite do campo, caso isso aconteça ele traz o campo em branco.

Também existe uma opção no relatório chamada *Stretch With Overflow*, da qual expande o tamanho do campo de acordo com o tamanho do texto.